# Is in all 'superluminal signaling' setups, entanglement involved?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Nonlinear extension of QM may lead to the 'superluminal signaling' so that it seems to violate the finite speed limit. I am wondering if it's true that in all such kind of 'superluminal' setups, entanglement plays a certain role?  Or is there any 'superluminal signaling' using nonlinear QM that does not need entanglement?

If this is the case that all superluminal signaling needs entanglement somehow, then I prefer to regarding such kind of 'superluminal signaling' as faked since we can not be sure such kind of non-local signaling between entangled subsystems is really 'non-local', if entanglement is really related with the construction of spacetime as some researchers claimed. At least before we know the ground truth of their relationship, it seems not 100% safe to call it 'non-local signaling', it might be in fact local. Is this possible?

Comment: superluminal signaling ? Please, could you provide a link to some publication ? TY

Comment: J. Bub and A. Stairs, Quantum interactions with closed timelike curves and superluminal signaling, [arXiv:1309.4751v4](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.4751v4)

Comment: There are no closed timelike curves in reality. You can always derive anything with logic if you start with something that's false. Physics can't save you from gigo, either. Having said that, gigo considerations can be quite useful to help with an exploration of the limits of a theoretical framework.

Comment: @ CuriousOne I agree with you there we do not have a CTC now. But we can not exclude its possibility. There is also some work to simulate CTC and did find some experimental results to confirm our prediction, for example [Experimental Simulation of Closed Timelike Curves](http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.05014v1)

Answer (score 2):

Newtonian mechanics is a setup which allows for superluminal signalling yet does not involve entanglement. The same is true for non-relatistic quantum mechanics: It also does not have any universal bound on the speed at which information is propagated, and does not require entanglement for that.

Of course, all these theories are not valid in the relativistic regime, but then again, any other extension of QM which allows for superluminal signalling is for the very least purely speculative and probably also in contradiction with something we know (or we believe in).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/111120)

Comment: @JonCuster Why does this not provide an answer to the question? The question is whether all physical setups (=theories) which allow for superluminal communication involve entanglement.  This is not the case.

Comment: The question asks about quantum systems. Newtonian mechanics lacks the whole concept of entanglement. So, your answer fails to address the question.

Comment: Well, then I read the question differently then you did. But if it's about QM, it is also fine: Non-relativistic QM is perfectly fine with superluminal signalling even if no entanglement is involved. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: What I mean is that let's consider the problem under the assumption that we respect relativity(which we generally believe) and try to update QM(in which there are something we are not very clear, for example, measurement problem, entanglement). Or maybe there are some designs that do not use entanglement, but why using entanglement is so popular on this topic?

Comment: Since entanglement based design is more popular, does this mean most people prefer entanglement based solution than other mechanisms? This observation itself says something.

Comment: To clarify my question, in fact I am only thinking of a nonlinear extension of QM to allow the superluminal signaling. I am wondering under such a condition, if we have to let entanglement to play a role, then it might be the case that still it's not really superluminal signaling. So relativity is not violated.

Comment: @X.Dong How can you have superluminal signalling which is "not really superluminal signalling"?  This does not make any sense.

Comment: @Norbert What I mean here is that the so called 'superluminal signaling' based on entanglement, should be re-checked, it's superluminal in the conventional sense, but we can not be 100% percent sure that this is really the case.

Comment: @X.Dong This does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @Norbert Assuming that entanglement does play a role in the construction of spacetime(quite possible I think), then we cannot ignore the influence of the entanglement used in these 'superluminal signaling' on our concept of what's 'local'. In fact if you take 2 qubits as a twistor, then any maximally entangled 2 qubits is correspondent to a light ray in Minkowski space time, but all other states are not (except for a set with 0 probability). So I do not believe this is only a coincident.

Comment: @Norbert The entangled state used here may violate the spacetime structure as in the ER=EPR case, there it's assumed that entanglement has a consequence on spacetime structure. Before we can exclude the possibility that entanglement is related with spacetime structure, it's never safe to claim what's 'local' when entanglement is involved.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, which may or may not meet the rules you have in mind.

If you're [allowed to perform post-selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostBQP), then you can communicate by post-selecting on a previously-entangled qubit containing the message you wanted to send:

[image: Post-selection allows decohered qubits to be used]

The operation of the "!Select" gate is $\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&1 \end{bmatrix}$. Clearly not unitary. The $x^{\lceil t \rceil}$ gate just alternates between do-nothing and apply-NOT, so I could check that both ON and OFF could be sent. I took a screensot when it was in the do-nothing state, corresponding to sending ON (and the green ON is displaying the state of the receiver's bit).

This setup weakens the requirement from "entangled" to just "correlated". Depending on your favorite interpretation, this may or may not be satisfying (e.g. in many worlds correlation is just a kind of entanglement).

Also you may philosophically object to using quantum suicide just to send a bit of information.

Comment: How do you set the qbits on the sending side ?

Comment: One could reasonably object that the receiver received the message already before it was sent.

Comment: @igael You either post-select on it being false or on it being true. My simulator only had a post-select-on-true gate so I either hit it with an X gate or not beforehand.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Sounds like a feature to me.

Comment: @Strilanc Yes, free will is overrated.

Comment: @Strilanc This post-selection based design is in fact similar to the P-CTC plan which is also on post-selection. There is a paradox that different observers may have different observations, since observer 1 may claim B measures his particle before A's action(NOT)(so B gets random results), observer 2 claims that B's measurement is after A's NOT action. So this 'non-local signaling' can not be verified unless we resolve the contradiction. Am I right on your design?

Comment: @X.Dong The synchronization issue depends on how the universe hypothetically implemented post-selection. For example, suppose the post-selection was [eventually consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) and took effect only in the sender's future light cone. Although, there would be observers who saw the wrong result, those observers all get discarded eventually. The remaining observers would remember having the right result all along, and any plans based on that fact will have succeeded. Avoiding discardation would require escaping the sender's hubble horizon.

Comment: @Strilanc Thanks. But the consistency of post-selection itself maybe even a harder problem. Do you think the contradiction between different observers are essentially from the consistency condition of the post-selection? Is there any other possibility?  Another thing I am not clear here, why you say it's 'correlated' qubits but not entangled? For me CNOT o H should generate EPR pairs if the input is in $|00\rangle$ and CNOT o H does generate entanglement.   Something wrong with my understanding?

Comment: @X.Dong Even with a single observer you can post-select yourself into a contradiction. Just take a qubit in the |0> state and post-select on it being |1>. As for correlated vs entangled: I'm basing the terminology on qubits whose value has escaped into the environment being considered decohered and classical-ish.

Comment: @Strilanc  Just take a qubit in the |0> state and post-select on it being |1>. Does this happen with probability 0?  From consistency point of view, is it still a real contradiction? In the P-CTC setup, this 0 probability of 'contradictional events' by post-selection means to rule out such events and is regarded as an advantage than Deutsch's D-CTC.